# In general what would be the run time of MPI_Scatter and MPI_Bcast to send n elements to p processors

Tags: time-complexity, mpi, big-o, broadcast, scatter

I wanted to understand the runtime complexity of MPI_Scatter and MPI_Bcast functions. Do they solely depend on number of processors or also on the number of elements we are sending.
Example:

- Broadcasting 1 integer to 10k processors
- Broadcasting array of 100 integers to 10k processors
- Scattering 10000 elements to 200 processors
- scattering 10000 elements to 1000 processors

I tried to understand the runtime by using MPI_Wtime as below and found that both scatter and broadcasts runtime depend on the number of processors only. Is this statement correct?

```
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0)
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Scatter(&data, n/p, MPI_INT, &temp_data, n/p, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //MPI_Bcast(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(rank==0)
        t2 = MPI_Wtime();

    cout << "Time taken" " << t2-t1 << endl;
```

The conclusion i desire is to be able to tell an approximation that the runtime of scatter and broadcast would be O(log p) where p is the number of processors.

Comment: The MPI standard does not, nor do any of its predecessors, mandate the implementation of the routines it contains.  If you look at sources you are likely to find that different libraries have chosen different approaches, and that they have varied their approaches over the 20+ year history of MPI.  You may also find that some MPI libraries contain multiple implementations to be used depending on the hardware (particularly the interconnect) they are run on.

Comment: Generally speaking, the runtime depends on both number of MPI tasks and message size. It also depends on the algorithm used by the MPI library, the interconnect(s) involved and the topology of your cluster.

Comment: In addition to the remarks above, some hardware might have specific capabilities that the MPI library can detect and take advantage of. For example, features like hardware multicast at switches' level might just permit to render calls to `MPI_Bcast()` pretty-much time-independent of the number of processes involved in the communication.